# Как ввести дробь через cin?

Tags: c++

С помощь scanf я могу ввести дробь таким образом:

```
scanf("%d/%d", &chys, &zn);
```

Как сделать подобное через cin?

Comment: Ваш вариант разрешает лишние пробелы после `/`, но не разрешает пробелы перед `/`. Вам так и нужно? Это важно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char c = 0;
std::cin >> chys >> c >> zn;
// Сгенерировать ошибку, если `c` не равно `/`
```

Отличите такого варианта в том, что он допускает лишние пробелы перед `/`, в то время, как ваш исходный вариант - не допускает. Если вам дорого именно такое поведение, то можно

```
std::cin >> chys >> std::noskipws >> c >> std::skipws >> zn;
```